# How to properly check if index exists, then use index to get value, then delete index & value from array javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I know the title was a mouthful, but describes what I need to do here. I will admit I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this out!

I'm trying to create a discount calculator and this is my first time using arrays.

Here's the code I have so far...

```
    dTrackerArray = [];
    //Create Array

    dTrackerArray.push( [var1, var2] );
    //Add Variables to Array

    var check = $.inArray(var1, dTrackerArray);
    // Checking to see if variable exists, keeps returning -1!!!

    alert(JSON.stringify(dTrackerArray));
    // Even though I have this right under it which alerts the array clearly showing var 1 and var 2 exist!
```

Once I've figured out how to properly check the array, I'd like to retain the value of the pair (in a variable perhaps), and then remove the pair from the array.

I'm sorry If this was a little hard to read or understand!

Comment: You don't add a veriable to your array. You add an array. [val, val] is an array litteral. Try  dTrackerArray = [var1, var2]; and delete the push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a multidimensional array (`[var1, var2]` becomes an object within the `dTrackerArray` array.)

Try pushing `var1` and `var2` separately.

```
 dTrackerArray.push(var1);
 dTrackerArray.push(var2);
```

Comment: Or `dTrackerArray.push(var1, var2);`

Answer (score 2):

You are adding an array that contains `var1` and `var2` to the `dTrackerArray` array.

Use this syntax instead:

```
dTrackerArray.push(var1);
dTrackerArray.push(var2);

// Or this syntax
dTrackerArray.push(var1, var2);

// Or this syntax
dTrackerArray = [ var1, var2 ];
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bEYtj/) to demonstrate.